# Django view not passing IP address data from form

Tags: python, django

Trying to do something simple here where I pass an IP address from a form to another view. Previously I had success following beginner tutorials. If someone could point me back to what I'm missing that would be a huge help.

model:

```
class GenericIP(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    genericip = models.GenericIPAddressField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

form:

```
class IpForm(forms.Form):
    gateway = ModelChoiceField(queryset=GenericIP.objects.order_by('name').values_list('genericip', flat=True).distinct())
```

views:

```
def TestCreate(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form1 = IpForm()
        return render(request, 'create_test.html', {'form1' : form1} )
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form1 = IpForm()
            if form1.is_valid():
                genericip = form1.cleaned_data
                genericip.save()
            return render(request, 'create_test.html', {'genericip' : genericip} )

def RunTest(request, genericip=""):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Server = genericip
    return HttpResponse(Server)
```

URLS:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.TestCreate, name='create_test'),
    path('run_test', views.RunTest, name='run_test',),
    ]
```

template:

```
{% block content %}
<form action="{% url 'run_test' %}"method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form1 }}
    <input type='submit' class="btn btn-success" value='Run Test'>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

So what's happening is when I hit the button to run the test, I don't get anything for the httpresponse. The post data for the TestCreate view does show variable "genericip" and input "192.168.100.100" but that data is not posting correctly to the runtest view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the **RunTest** function, you are getting the genericip value as a function argument.But in your scenario you are sending the genericip vaule in the form of **form submit**. So you should try some thing like this,

```
def RunTest(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ip = request.POST.get('gateway') # Some thing with form field name
        Server = ip
    return HttpResponse(Server)
```

Hope this helps you, if anything please let me know.

Comment: @PA_Commons, Learning is a always good, gohead and good luck, and please dont use Sir and all, just call by the actual names. Thanks you

Answer (score 2):

You aren't adding the POST data to the form instance in the post request - you're just instantiating an empty `IpForm` instance.

Try something like this in the appropriate section of your code:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form1 = IpForm(data=request.POST)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This works wonders for manipulating the form data in the create_test view.